# I am trying to automate a report using google sheets and I would like to increment the range ( column, row) so that I do not over write a data

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

//how do I do this dynamically because every week I need to copy 7 days of new data continuing from the last cell loc copied to so that I am not overwriting previous data thxxxx

```
function csFunction() {

  //Create an object that holds filenames, then loop through to copy data

  var Object1 = {
    Filenames:['temp1.csv','temp2.csv']
  };


  var len= Object1.Filenames.length; //holds length of Obj.file
  // Loop through Switch statement
  for(var i=0; i < len; i++){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
    var sourceSheet = Object1.Filenames[i]; 
    var destinationSheet = "Data";
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,19,11); //spreadsheet range:(row,column,numRows,numColumns)


    //switch Statement 1 for each report filename

    switch(sourceSheet){
      case"temp.csv":
        //Copies data from cell location in the report temp
        var cell1 = range.getCell(13,4).getValue();
        var cell2 = range.getCell(14,4).getValue();
        var cell3 = range.getCell(15,4).getValue();
        var cell4 = range.getCell(16,4).getValue();
        var cell5 = range.getCell(17,4).getValue();
        var cell6 = range.getCell(18,4).getValue();
        var cell7 = range.getCell(19,4).getValue();

        //Copies data to new location data
        targetSheet.getRange("E4").setValue(cell1.substring(0,6));
        targetSheet.getRange("E5").setValue(cell2.substring(0,6));
        targetSheet.getRange("E6").setValue(cell3.substring(0,6)); 
        targetSheet.getRange("E7").setValue(cell4.substring(0,6)); 
        targetSheet.getRange("E8").setValue(cell5.substring(0,6)); 
        targetSheet.getRange("E9").setValue(cell6.substring(0,6)); 
        targetSheet.getRange("E10").setValue(cell7.substring(0,6));   
        break;
```

Comment: Where do you want to increment the columns and rows and why both? where you are getting the values or where you are setting them? Or where you are getting the range?

Comment: I have 12 columns that I need to update weekly with data, in the example I am just updating 1 column * 7 rows which is 1 week of data for one report.  I am importing several reports .csv and copying the data from the .csv to googlesheet. I need the code to be dynamic , every week when the .csv is imported the data needs to append from where the last week left off. I want to declare a global object that stores last row values and gets updated not sure how to declare global variables on google sheets thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the number of the last row you've filled in your Properties. 
Properties for apps script are a kind of local DB which you can save data in.

For example:

```
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
documentProperties.setProperty('LAST_ROW_PREVIOUS_ITERATION', '20');
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties

Comment: ok thank you I will try that.  is there a way to store last row in a global object? in google sheets/ but ya I can see what I can do with your example thx

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to just append rows:

```
sheet.appendRow(["every","column","has","a","value"]);
```

You can also ask for the lastRow, and use that number:

```
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,5).setValue("value to be inserted");
```

Try to avoid using getCell, it will give an error when out of boundary

```
var row = 1000000;
var col = 1;
// preferred way
Logger.log(sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue()); // gives empty string
// don't use getCell
Logger.log(sheet.getDataRange().getCell(row, col).getValue()); // gives error when there are < 1000000 rows
```